# Perl HTTP request : POST fails while GET succeeds

Tags: perl, http

When I try to submit a POST request with Perl, it often ends in a 301 redirect to the homepage. Here is the code :

```
use LWP::UserAgent;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

# This does not work
my $url = 'http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search2';
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url);
$req->content('MovieName=the+terminator+(1996)');


# Pass request to the user agent and get a response back
print $req->as_string."\n";;
my $res = $ua->request($req);
if (!$res->is_success) { 
  print $res->status_line, "\n"; 
}
else { 
  print "Success in posting search\n";
}
```

In order to make it work, I have to manually use Firefox, go to the url (!). Then the script works. However, using a GET request works flawlessly :

```
# This works
my $url = 'http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/search2?MovieName=the+terminator+(1996)';
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
```

Why is that ?

Comment: *what* worked after going to the url in Firefox?  what did you do after just going to the url?

Comment: The script is supposed to return the html corresponding to the results of the POST request. Just launching the script stops at an error, so I went to the result page directly with Firefox. **Then** starting the script show the correct html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site doesn't expect a `POST` to that URL, so it redirects you to back to the search page.

Firefox will use `GET`, not `POST`, if you just put the URL into the address line, that's why it works.

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why a `POST` works in search.cpan.org as shown in [this tutorial](http://www.emunix.emich.edu/~evett/BioinformaticsTools/Lecture18_WebAccess.html) ? In both cases, there is a form waiting for `GET`.

Comment: @alex_reader: Because that particular form on `search.cpan.org` is written to use `POST` and not `GET`. Firefox uses the HTML that the site returns to determine which method to use to send the form information. You should do the same.

Comment: @gangabass: I couldn't reproduce behaviour like that, and I'm sceptical about it because two different HTTP clients should function independently, even if they have the same IP address. This Perl code doesn't even use cookies. If someone can give precise instructions how to recreate the behaviour then I will take a look.